# An error occurred when rendering a template

Tags: templating, error

I have an odd problem.

When I render a simple HTML template without any link to the Control Panel, I get the following message on random pages:

> An error occurred when rendering a template

Whenever I change I can't seem the remove this error or find the problem / solution.

Also I cannot access the Control Panel.

Can you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you enable [devMode](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode), reproduce the error, then update your original question with the full stack trace leading up to the error?

Answer (score 4):

You can receive this error if you have uploaded a Craft website and your `craft/storage/runtime/cache` and `craft/storage/runtime/complied_templates` folders are not writable.

We made these folders writable and resolved the error.

Answer (score 1):

**Disk usage over quota** is a possible cause for the error message `An error occurred when rendering a template` in Craft CMS v2.x.

In this case, you will see the same when trying to access the control panel, regardless of dev mode setting.